# Hiding/showing grandchild pages in a menu in Wordpress 3.3.2

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, children

I have a menu issue I'd like some help with please.

I am using wordpress 3.3.2 with theme Twenty Eleven.

I am using two templates, the default wordpress showcase and a custom page template named products.

I currently have this sub navigation tree (showcase template):

- -Markets & products

  - Agriculture
  - Aerospace
  - Defence
  - Industrial

The code I am using to get the above result is:

```
       <?php

        //$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=1&depth=1');

if($post->post_parent && $post->post_parent!=0){
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=2");

}else{
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
     }
 if ($children) { ?>
    <div id="subNav">
        <ul>        
        <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

When I select the agriculture page (product template), I am presented with this structure:

- Marketing & products

  - Agriculture

    - Grandchild page 1
    - Grandchild page 2
  - Aerospace

    - Grandchild page 1
    - Grandchild page 2
  - Defence
  - Industrial

The agriculture grandchild pages are on display but the aerospace grandchild pages should be hidden.

The current code I am using is:

```
    <?php

       //$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=1&depth=1');
    // && $post->post_parent!=0
    if($post->post_parent){
    //siblings
    $textTest = 'siblings';
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=2");
     }else{
            $textTest =  'children';
                    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
          }
       if ($children) { ?>
        <div id="subNav">
            <? echo $textTest;?>
            <ul>        
               <?php echo $children; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

So what I would like to know is; given:
that the marketing page has a parent of 0
that it has children aerospace and agriculture
that they have children also (grandchildren to marketing)

Is there a way I can display:
the children of marketing when on that page
the children of agriculture (for example) when on that page, or on one of it's children pages - so that only these grandchildren show and also the siblings of agriculture (children of marketing), but not the children of it's siblings?

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

The **if else** you r using is causing conflict.

Use a `meta value` for each page. which determines the menu type to show on the screen.

**ELSE:**

With this code the menu will show it will show you full menu always.

as when you are on the  `Agriculture` page it will check to see if it has parent or not, where in this case the parent of your `Agriculture` page is the `Marketing & products` page then it selects the parent page.

and all the child pages of `Marketing & products` are displayed in the link.

Comment: meta values support can be added for each post type as required well the `pages` and `posts` are already equipped with the meta values. there is a column below the description for meta values. where you can add meta values and their name. You can also create custom meta box for the same purpose. while in page template you can get the post meta value for the given key. and can use it accordingly. Well i think you dont know how to code in wordpress properly. I will suggest learning `GENESIS` frame work and read documentation of wordpress. It is a powerful tool for those who know.